# OLEDB Excel single quote error

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OLEDB, Writing Excel cell without leading apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755621/oledb-writing-excel-cell-without-leading-apostrophe)

I'm using this code:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
string sql = null;
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\test_excel.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
MyConnection.Open();
myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

sql = "CREATE TABLE EmployeeData (Id char(255), Name char(255), BirthDate date)";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

sql = "INSERT INTO EmployeeData (Id, Name, BirthDate) values ('AAA', 'Andrew', '12/4/1955')";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

MyConnection.Close();
```

The code works but my problem is single quote (see image below)

How to fix?

[example of problem http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/e32f9.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/e32f9.jpg)

Comment: This is "by design" behavior to force string type - I don't think you can avoid it. What about creating pure text `.csv` file instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should always to use parametrized queries. They're safe against injection, special characters and make your code more readable.

```
OleDbCommand cm = MyConnection.CreateCommand();
cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EmployeeData (Id, Name, BirthDate) values (@Id, @Name, @BirthDate)";
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", "AAA");
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "'Andrew");
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", new DateTime(1955, 4, 12));
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Rubens Farias Thank you for code but I do not want single quote, my code each cell insert single quote, How to fix ?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understood; can you please update your question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change

```
('AAA', 'Andrew', '12/4/1955')
```

into

```
("AAA", "Andrew", "12/4/1955")
```

?

Comment: i tried your code but it didn't work