# ADODB query updates Excel cell as escaped text

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, adodb

I'm trying update a cell within an Excel 2003 spreadsheet, but the problem that I'm having is that Excel adds a single quote to the front of my value. Is there any way to enter the value as an integer and not as an escaped string?

Thanks!!

```
Const filePath = "C:\1.xls"

Dim ado: Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ado.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""" _
                    & filePath & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"

ado.CursorLocation = 3
ado.Open

ado.Execute "UPDATE [Sheet1$A1:A1] SET F1 = 1;"

ado.Close
```

The above code updates cell A1 to `'1`

Comment: Its the OLEDB driver rather than ADO, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755621/oledb-writing-excel-cell-without-leading-apostrophe

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like the leading apostrophe is unavoidable :(

Comment: FWIW similar code I have that INSERTS into the sheet does not experience this.

Comment: Do you mind sharing this code?

Comment: `ado.Execute "CREATE TABLE [Sheet1$] (COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR)"
ado.Execute "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$]  VALUES (1, 'CAKE')"`

Comment: I managed to solve this with hints from Alex and onedaywhen. Can't self-answer yet but it's basically to set the Excel cell type beforehand!

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the [combination of registry values and existing data](http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2004/06/03/external-data-mixed-data-types/) is causing the data type of the column to be considered as text. Note that when using the OLE DB provider for ACE/Jet, Excel has but one numeric type, being `FLOAT` (Double).

To discover the considered data type, try running this:

```
Const filePath = "C:\1.xls"

Dim ado: Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ado.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""" _
                    & filePath & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"

ado.CursorLocation = 3
ado.Open

Dim rs
Set rs = ado.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT TYPENAME(F1) FROM [Sheet1$A1:A1];")
MsgBox rs.GetString

ado.Close
```

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve this with the help of hints from Alex K and onedaywhen.

The solution is to simply format the Excel cell(s) that I want to update with the correct type (number, custom, etc.) before running my script.

The strange thing is that I'm sure I tried this a few days ago and it didn't work...but I guess it must have been late in the day!